# Sum of inversions of variables

Tags: python, math, sum

How could I create a function which counts a **sum** of all **inverse values** from the given **list**?

```
lst = [1,2,3]

def sum_inv(lst):
   # what to put here? 

sum_inv([1,2,3]) = 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3
```

Do you have any advices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
def sum_inv(lst):
   return sum(1/x for x in lst)
```

As ozgur pointed out in the comments, this will throw an exception if lst contains any 0's. If you want to ignore any 0's and avoid the exception then you can add a check in the comprehension to ignore those values.

```
def sum_inv(lst):
   return sum(1/x for x in lst if x != 0)
```

Comment: No need to create a list for this (unless you're stuck with python 2.3). Just `return sum(1/x for x in lst)`

Comment: Very true. Updated answer to reflect this optimization.

Comment: You should exclude all zeros from the list: `sum(1/x for x in lst if x != 0)`

Answer (score 1):

For Python2, you should use `1.0 / x` otherwise you'll get truncated divison

```
def sum_inv(lst):
   return sum(1.0 / x for x in lst if x != 0)
```